# Reference class fields disappearing

Tags: r, cran, reference-class

I decided to give Reference Classes another shot, but my first hello world is already giving me issues. What is going wrong here?

```
> memory <- setRefClass(
+   Class = "memory",
+   fields = list(state="vector"),
+   methods = list(
+     get = function() { return(state) },
+     set = function(x) { state <<- x }
+   )
+ )$new()

> memory$set(123)

> print(memory)
Reference class object of class "memory"
Field "state":
[1] 123

> memory$get()
[1] 123

> print(memory)
Reference class object of class "memory"
Field "state":
Error in methods::show(field(fi)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'show': Error in get(name, envir = .self) : 
  unused argument(s) (name, envir = .self)
```

Comment: In all likelihood, has to do with `get` being some sort of reserved name; your code works if I rename `get` to something else like `get.state`.

Comment: Ah great. Doesn't make me overly comfortable that `setRefClass` does not throw a warning for this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with [Reference Classes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/refClass.html) but according to the help page (`?ReferenceClasses`), I think that you have to add a `show` method to your class to be able to print automaticaly your object.

```
memory <- setRefClass(
          Class = "memory",
          fields = list(state="vector"),
          methods = list(
          get = function() { return(state) },
          set = function(x) { state <<- x },
          show = function() {methods::show(state)}
          )
          )$new()


memory$set(123)
print(memory)
#[1] 123

memory$get()
#[1] 123


print(memory)
#[1] 123
```

Hope this help